# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a React App and I'm getting this warning. I'm trying to make two API calls when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getWebsites();
  loadUserRatings();
}, []);
```

That's why I have an empty array, because I want to call it just once when the component gets mounted. But I'm still getting the warning, how can I fix it?

Those two functions are passed to the component using connect from react redux, the whole component looks like this:

```
const Wrapper = (props) => {
  const { getWebsites, loadUserRatings } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    getWebsites();
    loadUserRatings();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Websites />
      <Sync />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR**

You should add `getWebsites`, `loadUserRatings` to the dependencies array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getWebsites();
  loadUserRatings();
}, [getWebsites, loadUserRatings]);
```

React asks you to add variables (whose values may change) to the dependency array so that the callback can use updated values of those variables.

---

You might face an issue where the `useEffect`'s callback runs more times than intended. Consider the below example:

```
const Bla = (props) => {
 const foo = () => {
  console.log('foo')
 }

 useEffect(() => {
  foo();
 }, [foo])
 
 return <span>bla</span>
}
```

As `foo` is used inside `useEffect`'s callback, it is added to the dependencies. But every time the component `Bla` renders, a new function is created and `foo` changes. This will trigger the `useEffect`'s callback.

This can be fixed using the hook `useCallback`:

```
const foo = useCallback(() => {
  console.log('foo');
}, []);
```

Now, when `Bla` rerenders, a new function will still be created but `useCallback` will make sure that `foo` doesn't change (memoization) which helps in preventing `useEffect`'s callback from running again.

**Note:** If there are variables that are used inside `foo` that change over time, they should be added to the `useCallback`'s dependencies array so that the function uses updated values.

Comment: @nick keep in mind that if `getWebsites()` and `loadUserSettings()` are passed down as function expressions rather than static definitions, then this will cause the `useEffect()` to trigger every time `Wrapper` renders. See my answer for how to deal with that scenario.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I updated my answer, we can also memoize them as I did, is that correct?

Comment: @Ramesh `useCallback()` takes two arguments, not one. You can't use `useCallback()` to get around this, it has to be initialized as state.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts can we pass an array like `[props.getWebsites]` as the second argument instead?

Comment: @Ramesh no because that's no different than using `getWebsites()` directly. I think your initial answer was fine, my answer already addresses what to do when encountering un-memoized functions.

Comment: @nick Make sure that the functions that are being passed are memoized properly, if they aren't, then follow Patrick's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it's not typical to pass un-memoized functions down via `props` like this.

```
// don't do this

<Wrapper
  getWebsites={() => fetchJson('websites').then(setWebsites)}
  loadUserRatings={() => fetchJson('ratings').then(setUserRatings)}
/>
```

If they are correctly memoized (using a hook like `useCallback()`, or by being defined outside of any component), then it's safe to pass them to the `deps` of your `useEffect()` without any difference in behavior. Here's an example that fixes the scenario above.*

```
// do this

const fetchJson = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json());

const Parent = () => {
  const [websites, setWebsites] = useState([]);
  const [userRatings, setUserRatings] = useState({});

  // useCallback creates a memoized reference
  const getWebsites = useCallback(
    () => fetchJson('websites').then(setWebsites),
    [setWebsites]
  );
  const loadUserRatings = useCallback(
    () => fetchJson('ratings').then(setUserRatings),
    [setUserRatings]
  );

  ...

  <Wrapper
    getWebsites={getWebsites}
    loadUserRatings={loadUserRatings}
  />
```

* <sub>`useState()` memoizes the dispatch function in its return value, so technically it would be safe to pass `[]` as the `deps` to each `useCallback()` here, but I believe that specifying the dispatch functions as dependencies helps improve clarity by explicitly communicating the author's intent, and there's no disadvantage to passing them.</sub>

[Ramesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61085102/1541563) is sufficient for this situation.

---

If you find that you're stuck with the first scenario, then, as a last resort, you can initialize `props` into your component's state like this.

```
const Wrapper = (props) => {
  const [{ getWebsites, loadUserRatings }] = useState(props);

  useEffect(() => {
    getWebsites();
    loadUserRatings();
  }, [getWebsites, loadUserRatings]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Websites />
      <Sync />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: @Luze I disagree personally with the claim that this is a "great pattern". I prefer to treat initializing `props` into state as a last resort approach if memoizing by other means is too inconvenient, which it usually isn't.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think using `useCallback` hook with necessary dependencies in the parent component and then passing these functions is a good approach.

Comment: @Ramesh I elaborated on your comment in my answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Nice, one thing I want to say is you can skip `setUserRating`, `setWebsites` from adding to the dependencies because react makes sure that they are properly memorized. React also doesn't show  any warning when we don't add them. This is because the function comes from `useState` hook but not user-defined. Nevertheless, it is okay to add them too.

Comment: @Ramesh see the footnote I added.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah, I totally agree. I've seen some react projects doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `getWebsites` and `loadUserRatings` to the dependencies of `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getWebsites();
  loadUserRatings();
}, [getWebsites, loadUserRatings]
```

All variables defined outside the `useEffect` hook need to be added, with the stipulation that they're defined in the body of the component or custom hook the useEffect() is called from, or passed down from parameters. Variables defined outside of the component or custom hook don't need to be added to the dependencies list. ([memoization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations)) It's one of the lesser known [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

---

Note: (this doesn't work for your scenario as your functions are passed down through the props) You can also wrap your function in a `useCallback` hook or define the variables you need inside the `useEffect` hook itself if you don't want to add it to the dependencies of your `useEffect` hook.

Comment: _All variables defined outside the `useEffect` hook need to be added_, with the stipulation that they're defined in the body of the component or custom hook the `useEffect()` is called from, or passed down from parameters. Variables defined outside of the component or custom hook don't need to be added to the dependencies list.